# Does runit reap orphan processes?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, phusion, runit

I am writing a small Docker container based on [Phusion baseimage](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker) which provides runit out of the box.

I put Cassandra and Opscenter agent in my container.  Both are started as service under /etc/service (as in the doc).

This [blog post](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/) mentions that my_init would collect zombie processes, but is vague about what it does with orphan processes.

Here's an example output of `ps -ef` in my Docker container:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 -u /sbin/my_init
root        27     1  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/runsvdir -P /etc/service
root        28    27  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 runsv sshd
root        29    27  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 runsv syslog-ng
root        30    27  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 runsv cron
root        31    27  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 runsv cassandra
root        32    27  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 runsv syslog-forwarder
root        33    27  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 runsv opscenter-agent
root        34    32  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 tail -F -n 0 /var/log/syslog
root        35    30  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
root        36    29  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 syslog-ng -F -p /var/run/syslog-ng.pid --no-caps
root        37    31 43 06:05 ?        00:00:10 java -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPrio
root        38    33  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /usr/local/opscenter/datastax-agent-5.2.0/bin/datastax-agent -f
root       471    38 51 06:05 ?        00:00:11 /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.8.0_51/bin/java -Dagent-foreground=yes -Xmx128M -Djclouds.mpu.parts.magnitude=100000 -Djclouds.mpu.parts.size=1
root       494     0  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 bash
root       761   494  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 ps -ef
```

Note `runsv opscenter-agent` (pid 33) starts a child process which is a bash call (pid 38) with a child process (pid 471).

Then I ran `sv stop opscenter-agent`, and `ps -ef`:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 -u /sbin/my_init
root        27     1  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/runsvdir -P /etc/service
root        28    27  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 runsv sshd
root        29    27  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 runsv syslog-ng
root        30    27  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 runsv cron
root        31    27  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 runsv cassandra
root        32    27  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 runsv syslog-forwarder
root        33    27  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 runsv opscenter-agent
root        34    32  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 tail -F -n 0 /var/log/syslog
root        35    30  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
root        36    29  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 syslog-ng -F -p /var/run/syslog-ng.pid --no-caps
root        37    31 19 06:05 ?        00:00:11 java -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPrio
root       471     1 20 06:05 ?        00:00:11 /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.8.0_51/bin/java -Dagent-foreground=yes -Xmx128M -Djclouds.mpu.parts.magnitude=100000 -Djclouds.mpu.parts.size=1
root       494     0  0 06:05 ?        00:00:00 bash
root       768   494  0 06:06 ?        00:00:00 ps -ef
```

Note pid 38 is gone, but pid 471 is now attached to `my_init`.

Is this the correct behavior?  What should I do to reap the child process?

Comment: My guess is that `my_init` should be responsible for reaping the child process, but I don't know why it doesn't.

Comment: Ok, [this link](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/blob/master/README.md#whats_inside_overview) clearly says that `my_init` should reap orphan processes.  So I don't know what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my_init` adopts orphaned processes and reaps them. But you misunderstood what "reaping" means. `my_init` does not tell it to exit; `my_init` only *waits* until it exits. You (or the process) are still responsible for making sure that it exits.

Comment: Thanks, I realized I misunderstood the term.